# class-loading throwing error in JBoss Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss

When I deployed my application `mono.ear` in JBoss 4.2, our `jboss-web.xml` has class-loading like below:

```xml
<class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance='false'> 
    <loader-repository> 
      com.mono.techstack:loader=mono.ear  
    </loader-repository> 
</class-loading>
```

Now I am migrating JBoss 4.2 to Wildfly 8.
When I deployed my application `mono.ear` in JBoss Wildfly, `class-loading` is throwing error. So how can I load class in Wildfly 8?

Comment: You should write here your stacktrace.

Comment: throwing what error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JBoss 4, but when I deploy to Wildfly 8 & 9, i'm not even using any class loading directives. All of the dependencies defined in Maven are loaded automatically. There's some information here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the exceptions?